# Combining lines with same string in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with a bunch of lines that looks like this:

`3 world
3 moon
3 night
2 world
2 video
2 pluto
1 world
1 pluto
1 moon
1 mars`

I want to take each line that contains the same word, and combine them while adding the preceding number, so that it looks like this:

`6 world
4 moon
3 pluto
3 night
2 video
1 mars`

I've been trying combinations with sed, but I can't seem to get it right. My next idea was to sort them, and then check if the following line was the same word, then add them, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to sort by word rather than the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum and sort:

```
awk -F" " '{c[$2]+=$1} END {for (i in c){print c[i], i}}' | sort -n -r
```